# how to show tax percentage of each product on wishlist page - magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, wishlist, percentage

I wants to show tax percentage of each item on wishlist page.

This is my wishlist product div please suggest me how to show tax percentage for each item.

```
 <div class="my-wishlist">
    <div class="page-title title-buttons">
        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isRssAllow() && $this->hasWishlistItems()): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getRssUrl($this->getWishlistInstance()->getId()); ?>" class="link-rss"><?php echo $this->__('RSS Feed') ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <h1><?php echo $this->getTitle(); ?></h1>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>

    <form id="wishlist-view-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/update', array('wishlist_id' => $this->getWishlistInstance()->getId())) ?>" method="post">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('top'); ?>
        <div class="fieldset">
            <?php if ($this->hasWishlistItems()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey');?>
                    <?php $this->getChild('items')->setItems($this->getWishlistItems()); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('items');?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('wishlist-table')</script>
            <?php else: ?>
                <p class="wishlist-empty"><?php echo $this->__('You have no items in your quote.') ?></p>
            <?php endif ?>
            <div class="buttons-set buttons-set2">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('control_buttons');?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <form id="wishlist-allcart-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/allcart') ?>" method="post">
        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
        <div class="no-display">
            <input type="hidden" name="wishlist_id" id="wishlist_id" value="<?php echo $this->getWishlistInstance()->getId() ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="qty" id="qty" value="" />
        </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var wishlistForm = new Validation($('wishlist-view-form'));
        var wishlistAllCartForm = new Validation($('wishlist-allcart-form'));

        function calculateQty() {
            var itemQtys = new Array();
            $$('#wishlist-view-form .qty').each(
                function (input, index) {
                    var idxStr = input.name;
                    var idx = idxStr.replace( /[^\d.]/g, '' );
                    itemQtys[idx] = input.value;
                }
            );

            $$('#qty')[0].value = JSON.stringify(itemQtys);
        }

        function addAllWItemsToCart() {
            calculateQty();
            wishlistAllCartForm.form.submit();
        }
    //]]>
    </script>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: anybody have any idea? please help

Answer (score 1):

For showing tax rate for each item you need to modify different phtml

**('app/design/frontend/base/dafault/template/wishlist/item/list.phtml').**
Inside foreach loop of wishlist items you need to write below code:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
$store = Mage::app()->getStore('default');
$request = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRateRequest(null, null, null, $store);
$tax_class_id = $product->getData('tax_class_id');
$rate = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRate($request->setProductClassId($tax_class_id));
```

You will get tax rate in $rate variable.

Comment: i showing error like  "Call to a member function getProductId() on a non-object"

Comment: please update same code in my file

Comment: please resolve my issue